# Does AngularJS translate provides any cross-reference mechanism?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I defined the name of some fields in my translation file and now I want to add some validation messages. This would be my translation file i.e:

```
{
  "field-name": "Name",
  "field-email": "Email",
  "required": "The field {{field}} is mandatory"
}
```

Is there any way to tell angular translate to cross-reference and pass as parameter the key of another translation? Something like:

```
<span translate translate-values="{field: 'field-name'}">
  required
</span>
```

or

```
<span translate translate-values="{field: 'field-email'}">
  required
</span>
```

I searched the docs and googled it but got no results.

If this is not possible, what would be the less bloated way to implement it? Take into account this is for a SPA (Single Page App) and the user can change the language without reloading the page.

Comment: Maybe crafting a custom interpolator?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to deal with it using `$translateProvider.postProcess()`.
It even works with `translate-values`, and nested `translate-values` parameters (with some care not to have two parameters with the same name)

Check it here: https://codepen.io/Onnizuka/pen/ePwKMK